# Mysql php query doesn't work with pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a question.

This is my query:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS Bedrijven_speci; 
CREATE VIEW Bedrijven_speci as SELECT bedrijfgegevens.id,
bedrijfgegevens.subbranche_id , 
(6371 * acos(cos(radians(51.61162253395352)) * cos(radians(bedrijfgegevens.latitude)) * cos(radians(bedrijfgegevens.longitude) - radians(5.535746802487663)) + sin (radians(51.61162253395352)) * sin (radians(bedrijfgegevens.latitude))) ) AS distance 
FROM bedrijfgegevens 
INNER JOIN subbranches on subbranches.id = bedrijfgegevens.subbranche_id 
INNER JOIN branches on branches.id = subbranches.branche_id 
INNER JOIN bedrijfgegevens_specialiteiten on bedrijfgegevens_specialiteiten.bedrijfgegevens_id = bedrijfgegevens.id 
INNER JOIN specialiteiten on specialiteiten.id = bedrijfgegevens_specialiteiten.specialiteiten_id 
WHERE branches.naam = "Fotografie" AND subbranches.naam = "fotografen"
GROUP BY bedrijfgegevens.id HAVING distance < 10; 
SELECT branches.naam as branche_naam, subbranches.naam as subbranche_naam, specialiteiten.naam as specialiteiten_naam 
FROM Bedrijven_speci 
INNER JOIN subbranches on subbranches.id = Bedrijven_speci.subbranche_id
INNER JOIN branches on branches.id = subbranches.branche_id 
INNER JOIN bedrijfgegevens_specialiteiten on bedrijfgegevens_specialiteiten.bedrijfgegevens_id = Bedrijven_speci.id 
INNER JOIN specialiteiten on specialiteiten.id = bedrijfgegevens_specialiteiten.specialiteiten_id

$query;

$sth = $pdo->prepare($query);
$sth->execute();
$fetch = $sth->fetchAll();
```

It works when I execute the query in Phpmyadmin. But when I execute in with PDO it returns an empty array. Can someone help me?

Comment: PDO is most likely throwing an error somewhere. Add error handling to your code.

Comment: I have this  if($sthFilter->errorCode() == 0) {
   echo 'k';
  } else {
   $errors = $sthFilter->errorInfo();
   echo $errors;
  } but it says "k"

Comment: a) `This is my query` - Those are three separate sql statements. b) Exactly what is $sth and how does its execute() method work? Can it run multi-queries?

Comment: where do you prepare the query?

Comment: I changed my code a bit, forgot a couple of things but apparently it won't execute multi queries in one statement

Comment: you're already preparing in the first line, so ditch `$sth->prepare();`

Comment: Plus, there's nothing assigned to `$query;` and you're dropping pure SQL into PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Just execute the statements one after another.
If required start a transaction before executing the the statements via [PDO::beginTransaction](http://docs.php.net/manual/de/pdo.begintransaction.php)

```
<?php
$queries = array(
    'DROP VIEW IF EXISTS Bedrijven_speci',
    'CREATE VIEW Bedrijven_speci as
        SELECT
            bedrijfgegevens.id,bedrijfgegevens.subbranche_id, 
            (6371 * acos(cos(radians(51.61162253395352)) * cos(radians(bedrijfgegevens.latitude)) * cos(radians(bedrijfgegevens.longitude) - radians(5.535746802487663)) + sin (radians(51.61162253395352)) * sin (radians(bedrijfgegevens.latitude))) ) AS distance 
        FROM bedrijfgegevens 
        INNER JOIN subbranches on subbranches.id = bedrijfgegevens.subbranche_id 
        INNER JOIN branches on branches.id = subbranches.branche_id 
        INNER JOIN bedrijfgegevens_specialiteiten on bedrijfgegevens_specialiteiten.bedrijfgegevens_id = bedrijfgegevens.id 
        INNER JOIN specialiteiten on specialiteiten.id = bedrijfgegevens_specialiteiten.specialiteiten_id 
        WHERE branches.naam = "Fotografie" AND subbranches.naam = "fotografen"
        GROUP BY bedrijfgegevens.id HAVING distance < 10',
        'SELECT branches.naam as branche_naam, subbranches.naam as subbranche_naam, specialiteiten.naam as specialiteiten_naam 
            FROM Bedrijven_speci 
        INNER JOIN subbranches on subbranches.id = Bedrijven_speci.subbranche_id
        INNER JOIN branches on branches.id = subbranches.branche_id 
        INNER JOIN bedrijfgegevens_specialiteiten on bedrijfgegevens_specialiteiten.bedrijfgegevens_id = Bedrijven_speci.id 
        INNER JOIN specialiteiten on specialiteiten.id = bedrijfgegevens_specialiteiten.specialiteiten_id'
);

$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->beginTransaction();
try {
    foreach( $queries as $q ) {
        $pdo->exec($q);
    }
}
catch(Exception $ex) {
    $pdo->rollBack();
    throw $ex;
}
$pdo->commit();
```